# How to parse Excel spreadsheets in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: excel, azure, parsing

I need to parse and extract Column information from an Excel spreadsheet using Azure Logic Apps

I have already setup the ability for my Logic App to retrieve the latest unread Emails from my Outlook. Also, my Logic App does a FOR EACH to read all attachments (from unread emails) and make sure they are Excel files (based on filename extension).

I have a basic Excel file that contains 3 columns "Product, Description, Price" I need to parse each row (only Product and Price) column.

I will add the ability to store that parsed into into my SQL table hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, you could use HTTP Request as well.

[image]

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Nancy.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConvertExcelToJSon
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("ConvertToJson")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            string blobName = data?.blobName;

            string[] splitBlob = blobName.Split('/');

            Stream blob = await GetBlobStreamAsync(splitBlob[1], splitBlob[2] + "/" + splitBlob[3]);
            DataSet ds = CreateDataSet(blob);
            List<Simple> simpleList = new List<Simple>();
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {

                return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(DataTableToJSON(table));

            }


            return blobName != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {blobName}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }



        public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    dict[col.ColumnName] = (Convert.ToString(row[col]));
                }
                list.Add(dict);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            return serializer.Serialize(list);
        }

        public static string AppSetting(this string Key)
        {
            string ret = string.Empty;
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Key) != null)
            {
                ret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Key);
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public static async Task<Stream> GetBlobStreamAsync(string containerName, string blobName)
        {
            Stream myBlob = new MemoryStream();
            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("AzureWebJobsStorage".AppSetting(), out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
            {
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
                CloudBlob myBloab = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
                await myBloab.DownloadToStreamAsync(myBlob);
                myBlob.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
            return myBlob;
        }
        public static DataSet CreateDataSet(Stream stream)
        {
            DataSet ds;
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            IExcelDataReader reader = null;
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            ds = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                {
                    UseHeaderRow = true,
                }
            });
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. My Azure Logic Apps skills are very green. I understand that to create an Azure Function I have to do this locally on my PC using Visual Studio. When doing so, do I create an empty one, a blob trigger, a http trigger... basically it is asking me for a trigger to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you call an Azure Function from your logic App and use the Function to convert the Excel into a JSON Object. (I am currently doing this very succesfully)  I use  ExcelDataReader parse to parse a Blob that the Logic App creates.  Send the blob location in the request and respond back with the JSON.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of your logic app flow from designer?