# How to store email attach csv file content as variable in azure logic app

Tags: excel, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I get a csv file as email attachment.I need a way to read email attachment and save that attachment as variable or directly read the attach file content and get data or store in blob storage.( If csv file save in blob , how we can read it. )

note - This csv file has data about system processes.I want to get only yes process from the attach csv file and continue the integration. 
ex- onboarding process | yes 
    billing  process | no

[image: Here is the steps I tried.]

Comment: Hi, may I know what does "yes no processes" mean ?

Comment: This excel sheet is about details of system process. It has which process is run or not. I want to get only yes process.  Ex- onboarding process - yes ,  Billing process - No.   Actually I want to save that excel sheet in file location of azure or directly read attachment and get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement about "**If csv file save in blob , how we can read it**", I can provide a solution for your reference, please refer to the steps below:

**1.** I have a csv file in my blob storage and its content show as below:

```
item,date,process
1,2020-01-01,yes
2,2020-01-01,no
```

**2.** Use "[Get blob content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#get-blob-content)" to get the content of the blob.
[image]

**3.** Search the action "Parse CSV" in you logic app.
[image]

It will ask you to input "API Key", you need to go to this [page](https://plumsail.com/documents/) first --> click "Start free trial", register an account and create a new API Key.
[image]
[image]
Copy the secret and paste it to your logic, it will allow you to connect Plumsail.

**4.** Input the "File Content" and the headers into the box, we can also add a new parameter "Skip first line" and set it "Yes"(this parameter will skip the header line and avoid two lines header in the expect table).
[image]

**5.** Then you can loop the "Body" from "Parse CSV" action and use a "If" condition to judge if the "process" equals "yes" or "no", and do what you want in each branch flow.
[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: If I have excel file. Can I use parser for excel files or are there any way to read excel files in blob storage.

Comment: @user5702902 As far as I know, there isn't a good way for us to parse the excel in logic app. If you want to parse the excel from blob storage in logic app, I suggest you to write a azure function to do this and call the function in your logic app. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761196/how-to-parse-excel-spreadsheets-in-azure-logic-apps). Or you can just parse the csv like I mentioned in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Plumsail offers an action in the Power Automate connector for parsing CSV files, which you might find useful. There is an article about this in the [Documentation](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/read-a-csv-file-and-bulk-generate-documents.html), and a video [Read CSV files in Power Automate and bulk generate documents](https://youtu.be/W5495sFCmoU?si=ramgFKIza5zkDNAK) that describes the process in detail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).