# how to convert CSV to JSON with | delimiter using Logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

We are getting csv file using  "|" delimiter, How we can convert this CSV files to JSON using Logic app. I've found many solution which can extract data using "," delimiter.

any inbuilt Connector within Logic app, Expecting not to use any 3rd party service.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't any inbuilt connector in logic app which can help us convert csv to json easily. You can go to this [feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/38929933-parse-csv) to vote for this feature to suggest microsoft to add this connector in logic app.

By the way, here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929429/how-to-store-email-attach-csv-file-content-as-variable-in-azure-logic-app/61949717#61949717) which I provided the solution about how to convert csv to json in logic app for your reference. If your csv file using "|" delimiter, you can try to use [replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace) method to replace the "|" with "," in your csv.

If you still don't want to use 3rd party service, you can refer to this post about how to convert csv to json just by logic app. But I think this solution is too much trouble.

Hope it helps~